# Why does assertAlmostEqual(-inf,-inf) fail?

Tags: python, unit-testing, numpy, infinity

Numpy's log method gives -inf for log(0). This value is comparable:

```
>>> np.log(0) == np.log(0)
True
```

Now in unittesting the following works fine:

```
self.assertEqual(np.log(0),np.log(0))
```

but this fails:

```
self.assertAlmostEqual(np.log(0),np.log(0))
```

Why is this behaviour like this? Is this a bug or intended? If intended, how can I check two float values to be almost equal, working also correctly for -inf?

Answer (score 5):

From the doc of unittest [assertAlmostEqual(a, b)](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual) is by default equivalent to `round(a-b, 7) == 0`. so in your case you have :

```
In [8]: np.log(0) - np.log(0)
Out[8]: nan

In [9]: round(np.log(0) - np.log(0), 7)
Out[9]: nan

In [11]: np.nan == 0
Out[11]: False
```

That explain why your test fail.

For making it work use [unittest2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2) here is an example:

```
import unittest2
import numpy as np

class Test_Assertions(unittest2.TestCase):
    def test_float_inf(self):
        self.assertAlmostEqual(float('inf'), float('inf'))

    def test_numpy_inf(self):
        self.assertAlmostEqual(np.log(0),np.log(0))


unittest2.main()
```

Output:

```
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

N.B: In unittest2 `assertAlmostEqual()` first test if the two objects are equal if yes so the result is yes else do the magic (almost equal) , this is why it work . It also should work in new python version (2.7 >) because most of them have the unittest2 functionality implemented (i'm not sure about this because i don't have python 2.7 > in my work station).

Hope this can help :)

Answer (score 4):

The difference between an Inf and any finite value is either Inf or -Inf. That's part of the IEEE754 specification.  Since `assertAlmostEqual` uses subtraction this explains the behaviour.

Here's the relevant table from the Intel x86 documentation for FSUB:

[image]

To solve your problem you are going to need special case handling for Inf.

Comment: Note that this special case belongs in `assertAlmostEqual`, not in his test code.  This is clearly a bug in `TestCase.failUnlessAlmostEqual`.

Comment: @Glenn I agree. I don't know how to file Python bug reports! Do you?

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that the difference between -∞ and -∞ can be as much as ∞. Therefore, they aren't really "almost equal".

If you want to ignore this special case, then something like this might be useful:

```
if valueA != valueB:
  self.assertAlmostEqual(valueA, valueB)
```

Comment: They're equal, but not almost [i.e. close to] equal? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Devin: indeed. Unfortunately the corner cases of IEEE floating point numbers (infinity, NaN, +/-0) are rarely intuitive. +/-0 is one of the rare cases that behaves pretty sane.

Comment: @Devin It does make sense. For example. Think of a large positive number, x say. Now square x. x^2 is less than infinity but a long way from x. Now consider x^x. It is less than infinity but but even further from x. And so on. That's just the nature of infinity.

Comment: @Devin: the idea is possibly that two calculation that both arrive at positive infinity could get there via **wildly** different calculations. So there's no way to say if the "same infinity" is meant. There *are* an infinite number of infinite values, after all.

Comment: @David @Joachim and yet if there is any difference between two numbers, they are not equal. So if the difference is large, obviously it is nonzero, and therefore infinity != infinity. And yet infinity == infinity. The logic above would imply otherwise.

Comment: @Devin: yes, I still agree with you that it doesn't make sense ;-)

Comment: @Devin It's because it's doing a subtraction when you call assertAlmostEquals. When you call assertEquals then it will indeed call == which is why it works. You can see all this if you read my answer.

Comment: @David I understand why it does it, but the reasoning above is not really sensical. The reason is because the implementation doesn't handle a certain special case that it could and that would make sense.